# asp.net WebApi add MediaTypeFormatter in webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I have a custom media formatter named `TestFormatter` in `TestFormatter.cs extending MediaTypeFormatter`. Now I want to add this formatter. One option is:

```
config.Formatters.Add(new BinaryMediaTypeFormatter());
```

what if I want to add this media type formatter in web.config file. I have seen

```
<webApi.webServer>
    <services>
      <replace serviceType="System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler, System.Web.Http" serviceClass="Slb.Avocet.WebApiServer.ExceptionHandling.GlobalExceptionHandler, Slb.Avocet.WebApiServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <replace serviceType="System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider, System.Web.Http" serviceClass="Slb.Avocet.WebApiServer.Documentation.XmlDocumentationProvider, Slb.Avocet.WebApiServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </services>
    <mediaTypeFormatters>
    </mediaTypeFormatters>
    <messageHandlers>      
    </messageHandlers>
  </webApi.webServer>
```

node in web.config file. But i do not know the right syntax to add it. I have tried googling but no success.

Comment: where have you seen it?

Comment: in default webconfig file.

Comment: under which section?

Comment: under <webApi.webServer>. Updated my question too for the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done through the use of config file settings only; unfortunately, you will need to write some code to get where you want to be.  This is because the web.config file is an ASP.NET / IIS construct and WebAPI was designed to be [self-hosted](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api) (outside of IIS / ASP.NET).

I recommend adding your own custom ConfigurationSection to the config file.  Add a MediaTypeFormatters property / element to your ConfigurationSection class, and have that property be a ConfigurationElementCollection.  Then, in your website's Global.asax, add some code that copies any MediaTypeFormatters in your custom collection over to the "live" collection attached to HttpConfiguration.  This [link](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/) contains an example of using a similar approach to set the HttpConfiguration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy property using web.config settings; while it's not exactly what you are trying to do it should provide a great starting point.

Comment: I accept this answer as a right one. After few more digging I found that there is no way to do it than making your custom node and accessing it.