# ASP MVC Receiving file from external application API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application that interfaces with an external API.  The problem that has me really stuck is downloading documents from the API and presenting them to the user for download.

The below code throws an exception at result = await response.GetResultAsync();.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage>    Download(int FileId)
{
var client = DataAccess.getApiClient();
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
var documentsApi = new DocumentsApi(client);
var response = await documentsApi.GetDownloadAsync(FileId);

result = await response.GetResultAsync<HttpResponseMessage>();

return result;
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpResponseMessage' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.
```

I can actually see the response in visual studio below:

```
{
Pragma: no-cache
x-server-name: APPAPI
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.eml"
Content-Length: 44549
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 11:56:37 GMT
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}.
```

Research suggest I need MediaFormatter so I've attempted to setup one up as follows but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
public class StreamMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{

    private static Type _supportedType = typeof(byte[]);
    private bool _isAsync = false;

    public StreamMediaTypeFormatter() : this(false)
    {

    }

    public StreamMediaTypeFormatter(bool isAsync)
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
        IsAsync = isAsync;
    }

    public bool IsAsync
    {
        get { return _isAsync; }
        set { _isAsync = value; }
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == _supportedType;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == _supportedType;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type,
        Stream stream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        Task<object> readTask = GetReadTask(stream);
        if (_isAsync)
        {
            readTask.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            readTask.RunSynchronously();
        }
        return readTask;
    }

    private Task<object> GetReadTask(Stream stream)
    {
        return new Task<object>(() =>
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        });
    }

    private Task GetWriteTask(Stream stream, byte[] data)
    {
        return new Task(() =>
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            ms.CopyTo(stream);
        });
    }



}
```

The formatter is registered in Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new StreamMediaTypeFormatter());
```

All I want to do is have the response file.eml presented to the user for download when the action is called.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
David

Comment: Creating a class is not enough, you need to register this media formatter. Please note this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831029/asp-net-webapi-add-mediatypeformatter-in-webconfig

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help.
I do actually have:
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new StreamMediaTypeFormatter());
in Global.asax.cs.
Same problem.